# Como puedo convertir un string a un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, string

estoy usando axios para obtener resultados de una API, esta me los devuelve en un objeto, del cual necesito solamente el campo latlng (coordenadas) y estan separadas por comas, ejemplo del resultado de uno de ellos en la consola

```
35.661857,139.693448
```

hasta el momento esta es la manera en la que los obtengo, pero necesito convertir `item.latlng` en un array

```
    axios.get(franchiseListRoute)
        .then((response) => {
            this.data = response.data;
            this.data.forEach((item) => {
                let latlng = item.latlng;
                console.log(latlng);
            });
        });
```

si utilizo JSON.parse obtengo el error

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 9

que creo que es por los puntos y de repente aparece una coma, que es el separador real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el metodo `.split()`. Lo que hace es separar/dividir un string y regresa el resultado como un array, en este caso lo que quieres es separar la longitud y latitud que esta separados por una coma.

```javascript
this.data.forEach((item) => {
  let latlng = item.latlng.split(',');
  
  // el resultado tendria este formato
  // [35.661857,139.693448]
});
```

La variable `latlng` ahora contiene un arreglo. Si el string que recibe es un string vacio el arreglo estaria vacio.

Mas acerca del metodo `.split()` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: perfecto, algo así buscaba, me estaba complicando con otros métodos, gracias!